# how to make a connected list of elements in Java

Tags: java, list, class, sorting, connection

i want to make a connected list of Student elements. The class Student must have only two fields(name and codeNumber).I also created a method to compare the names and if the names are equals then i compare codeNumbers.  this is because i must insert the elements low to high.
I created a class like:

```
class Student
    private String name;
    private int codeNumber;

    public Student(String name, int AM){
        this.name = name;
        this.codeNumber = codeNumber;
    }

    public int compareTo(Student other){
        int result;
        if(other.name.compareTo(this.name) == 0){
            result = 0;
            return result;
        }
        if(other.name.compareTo(this.name) < 0){
            result = 1;
            return result;
        }
        if(other.name.compareTo(this.name) > 0){
            result = -1;
            return result;
        }
        if(other.codeNumber > this.codeNumber){
            result = 1;
            return result;
        }
        if(other.codeNumber < this.codeNumber){
            result = -1;
            return result;
        }
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getcodeNumber(){
        return codeNumber;
    }   
}
```

And here is the problem. I need a StudentList class to make my own list.
So i created the class but im not sure if i have the right fields in this class.
I created 4 fields:
1.private Student studentElement;
2.private StudentList next = null; a reference to the next element 
3.private StudenList head; a reference to the start of the list
4.private int size = 0; to know the number of the elements
And here is my code:

```
class StudentList{
    private Student studentElement;
    private StudentList next = null;
    private StudentList head;
    private int size = 0;

    public StudentList(Student listEl){
        listElement = listEl;
    }

        public boolean containsElement(Student p){
        StudentList position = head;
        while(position != null){
            if(StudentElement.getName().equals(p.getName()) && studentElement.getAM() == p.getAM()){
                return true;
            }
            position = position.getNext();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

This is my code. Can anyone tell me if i have the right types of fields in my class and help me creating an insert method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

Prefer using `java.util.LinkedList`

and add the `Student` instances in the way you need. This will preserve the order in
which you add to the list

Comment: yes i know that but i have to make my own list so i cant use LinkedList

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the Java library list implementations such as `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` which do precisely what you want, no point in rolling-your-own.

Also learn about `Collections.sort()` if needed.

Your `Student` class should also implement the `Comparable` interface which (by a stroke of luck) has the same signature as your existing `compareTo` method.

Comment: yes i know ArrayList but in my exercise i have to create my own list.